# React state resets automatically

Tags: reactjs

I am new to React and have a problem with my React App.
I already searched for answers on stackoverflow and google but couldn't find any, maybe you could help me.

Code:

```
export default class blockchainElements extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            blockCounter: 0,
            blockchainElements: [
                { id, hashPrev, hashThis, data, nonce }
            ]
        }
        this.addBlockchainElement.bind(this);
        this.mineEvent.bind(this);
        this.mappingFunc.bind(this);
    }

    mineEvent = (index, e) => {
        const blockchainElements = Object.assign([], this.state.blockchainElements);
        while(blockchainElements[index].hashThis.substring(0, 4) !== "0000"){
            blockchainElements[index].nonce++;
            blockchainElements[index].hashThis = 
                Sha256.hash(blockchainElements[index].id + 
                blockchainElements[index].data + 
                blockchainElements[index].hashPrev + 
                blockchainElements[index].nonce);
            this.setState({blockchainElements: blockchainElements});
        }
        blockchainElements[index].mined = true;
        this.setState({blockchainElements: blockchainElements});
    }

    otherfunctions(...);
}

blockchainElement:

    const blockchainElement = (props) => {
        return(HTML-Code);    
    }
```

Problem:

In the function `mineEvent()` I use the "**setState**" function, which changes the state of the class afterward the desired state gets rendered for a second but then the page gets refreshed to its initial state.

I tried to debug the whole thing but couldn't get any information out of there.

Probably you don't have enouph information to help me, please tell me how I can help that you can help me.

Greetings

Comment: You can store the value in redux store instead

Comment: Do you mean the page gets refreshed to initial stage without you reloading the webpage?

Comment: @Think-Twice Even if you use redux, on page refresh, it will lead to initial state.

Comment: @ZenOut yes, but a refresh is happening without me wanting to do that

Comment: @Markus Förstel could you please post the whole class, including render?

Comment: Sure, one second

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It's by nature. When the page is refreshed the state will lead to the initial state. If you want to persist the state, you may use localStorage and load the state from localStorage when you update the state, also update to the localStorage.

Comment: Is there an option to not refresh the page?

Comment: No. User can hit refresh anyway.

Comment: Yes as desired. If he refreshes the page the state should be inital again. But it gets refreshed without me or the user wanting the page to refresh just after pressing the button which executes the function.

Answer (score 0):

```
import React from "react";
import Sha256 from "./sha256";
import BlockchainElement from "./blockchainElement";

import Button from 'grommet/components/Button';


export default class blockchainElements extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            blockCounter: 0,
            blockchainElements: []
        }
        this.addBlockchainElement.bind(this);
        this.mineEvent.bind(this);
        this.mappingFunc.bind(this);
    }

    addBlockchainElement = () => {
        const blockchainElements = Object.assign([], this.state.blockchainElements);
        blockchainElements[blockchainElements.length] = { 
            id: this.state.blockCounter, 
            hashPrev: (this.state.blockCounter !== 0 ? this.state.blockchainElements[this.state.blockCounter-1].hashThis : "0000000000000000000000"), 
            data: {amount: 0, from: "", reciever: ""}, 
            hashThis: "", 
            nonce: 0,
            mined: false
        }
        this.setState({blockCounter: this.state.blockCounter + 1});
        this.setState({blockchainElements: blockchainElements});
        console.log(this.state.blockchainElements);
        debugger;
    }

    mineEvent = (index, e) => {
        const blockchainElements = Object.assign([], this.state.blockchainElements);
        while(blockchainElements[index].hashThis.substring(0, 4) !== "0000"){
            blockchainElements[index].nonce++;
            blockchainElements[index].hashThis = Sha256.hash(blockchainElements[index].id + 
                blockchainElements[index].data + 
                blockchainElements[index].hashPrev + 
                blockchainElements[index].nonce);
            this.setState({blockchainElements: blockchainElements});
        }
        blockchainElements[index].mined = true;
        this.setState({blockchainElements: blockchainElements});
    }

    mappingFunc = () => {
        return(
            this.state.blockchainElements.map((blockchainElement, id)=>{
                return(
                    <BlockchainElement
                    id={blockchainElement.id}
                    hashPrev={blockchainElement.hashPrev}
                    data={blockchainElement.data}
                    hashThis={blockchainElement.hashThis}
                    nonce={blockchainElement.nonce}
                    mineEvent={this.mineEvent.bind(this, id)}/>
                );
            })
        );
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                {this.mappingFunc()}
                <Button label='Add Block'
                    onClick={this.addBlockchainElement}
                    primary={true}
                    secondary={false}
                    accent={false}
                    plain={false}
                    critical={false}
                />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

blockchainElement.js:

```
const blockchainElement = (props) => {
    return(
        <Box>
            <Form>
                <Header>
                    <Heading>
                        {props.id === 0 ? "Genesis-Block" : props.id}
                    </Heading>
                </Header>
                <FormFields>
                    <FormField label="Data">
                        <TextInput placeHolder="Amount of DATA" value={props.amount}/>
                        <TextInput placeHolder="From"/>
                        <TextInput placeHolder="Reciever"/>
                    </FormField>
                    <FormField label="Hashwert">
                        <div border="1px solid black" backgroundcolor="white">
                            {props.hashThis}
                        </div>
                    </FormField>
                    <FormField label="Hash zuvor">
                        <div border="1px solid black" backgroundcolor="white">
                            {props.hashPrev}
                        </div>
                    </FormField>
                    <FormField label="Nonce">
                        <div border="1px solid black" backgroundcolor="white">
                            {props.nonce}
                        </div>
                    </FormField>
                </FormFields>
                <Footer pad={{"vertical": "medium"}}>
                    <Button label='Mine'
                    type='submit'
                    primary={true}
                    onClick={props.mineEvent}/>
                </Footer>
            </Form>
        </Box>
    );
}
export default blockchainElement;
```

Comment: try to put console.log(...blockchainElements); above each setState in mineEvent, I think you are somehow using old state of state, otherwise dont know :-/

Comment: Well the desired state is getting written, but again instant refresh afterwards ofc.

Comment: I copied the code to my machine, and it works, the only thing I had to change was Sha256.hash( to Sha256( since i dont have your function

Comment: I dont think there is a problem in this component, try to put 
    componentWillMount() {
        console.log('mount');
    }
 in BlockchainElements and count check if it logs after the state refreshes

Comment: It only spits "mount" out, when i load the page the first time, and after getting refreshed

Comment: refreshed you mean browser refresh or, the state "refresh"

Comment: I mean the browser refresh. As if i press F5

Comment: well in that case, Iam sorry but I cant help you :-/  kinda out of ideas

Comment: btw https://codesandbox.io/s/7wrmj6yw1j here is sandbox with your code and it works, maybe try to slowly enhace with rest of your code, and hit me up when it break ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I debugged further and i got to this function.
After this function in react-dom.development.js the page gets refreshed.

```
function dispatchInteractiveEvent(topLevelType, nativeEvent) {
  interactiveUpdates(dispatchEvent, topLevelType, nativeEvent);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because page is getting refreshed and as a result, state is getting reloaded and not re-rendered. This is because blockchainElement.js, your button it of type submit. Submit will by default reload the page and hence you need to put preventDefaults.

Change to following code for this to work -->

```
<Footer pad={{"vertical": "medium"}}>
                <Button label='Mine'
                type='submit'
                primary={true}
                onClick={e => {e.preventDefault();props.mineEvent();}}/>
 </Footer>
```

This should work.